# delete random edges of a node till degree = 1 networkx

Tags: python, networkx

If I create a bipartite graph G using random geomtric graph where nodes are connected within a radius. I then want to make sure all nodes have a particular degree (i.e. only one or two edges).
My main aim is to take one of the node sets (i.e node type a) and for each node make sure it has a maximum degree set by me.  So for instance if a take node i that has a degree of 4, delete random edges of node i until its degree is 1.

I wrote the following code to run in the graph generator after generating edges.  It deletes edges but not until all nodes have the degree of 1.

```
for n in G:
    mu = du['G.degree(n)']
    while mu > 1:
            G.remove_edge(u,v)
    if mu <=1:
            break
return G
```

full function below:

```
import networkx as nx
import random

def my_bipartite_geom_graph(a, b, radius, dim):

    G=nx.Graph()
    G.add_nodes_from(range(a+b))
    for n in range(a):
        G.node[n]['pos']=[random.random() for i in range(0,dim)]
        G.node[n]['type'] = 'A'

    for n in range(a, a+b):
        G.node[n]['pos']=[random.random() for i in range(0,dim)]
        G.node[n]['type'] = 'B'

    nodesa = [(node, data) for node, data in G.nodes(data=True) if data['type'] == 'A']
    nodesb = [(node, data) for node, data in G.nodes(data=True) if data['type'] == 'B']

    while nodesa:
        u,du = nodesa.pop()
        pu = du['pos']
        for v,dv in nodesb:
            pv = dv['pos']
            d = sum(((a-b)**2 for a,b in zip(pu,pv)))
            if d <= radius**2:
                G.add_edge(u,v)


    for n in nodesa:
        mu = du['G.degree(n)']
        while mu > 1:
            G.remove_edge(u,v)
        if mu <=1:
           break
    return G
```

Reply to words like jared.  I tried using you code plus a couple changes I had to make:

```
def hamiltPath(graph):

    maxDegree = 2
    remaining = graph.nodes()
    newGraph = nx.Graph()
    while len(remaining) > 0:
        node = remaining.pop()
        neighbors = [n for n in graph.neighbors(node) if n in remaining]
        if len(neighbors) > 0:
            neighbor = neighbors[0]
            newGraph.add_edge(node, neighbor)
            if len(newGraph.neighbors(neighbor)) >= maxDegree:
                remaining.remove(neighbor)

    return newGraph
```

This ends up removing nodes from the final graph which I had hoped it would not.

Comment: I am not sure, how you intend to achieve it. Consider a star graph. How would you reduce the degree of each node to 1?

Comment: thanks for your comment Abhijit, I am actually working with a bipartite graph. I left this info out to simplify things but I now realise it actually complicates them.  So the main aim is to return one of the node sets to all have a degree of one.  So technically in my code replace "for n in G" with "for in nodesetA"

Comment: Please provide the full function if it is not too big. If it is too big, try to isolate your problem into a smaller one. Then try to explain what is the expect output, and what you are getting.

Comment: I know they claim it  experimental but still have you tried with [bipartite_random_regular_graph](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.generators.bipartite.bipartite_random_regular_graph.html#networkx.generators.bipartite.bipartite_random_regular_graph)

Comment: I would like u,v to be a random edge of node n. mu shuld be the degree of the node and so will be an the range of 1-number of nodes yes.

Comment: Consider the [following graph](http://postimage.org/image/798srvaeh/), can you clarify, how would you intend to reduce the degree esp w.r.t node 3?

Comment: Of course Abhijit, I can allow isolates in my final graph, nodes with zero degree.

Comment: and so all nodes connected to node 3 will have degree of zero except one

Comment: please correct your indentation. Currently it is not valid python. Do you confirm that the last `for` loop has the same indentation than the previous `while`? We cannot read in your mind so try to provide your actual code with the right formatting.

Comment: @Simon Hope this is an improvement simon, thank you.

Comment: I have to leave very soon so I don't have time to dig into this at the moment.  I am not familiar with the networkx package.  It appears in your code that you establish nodes and then edges for your initial graph.  In your edited version of the hamilt method I provided, you didn't add in those nodes.  Perhaps that could be an issue?  In other words if your graph consists of `G(V,E) = ({a, b, c}, {ab})` then maybe `c` is never added because it doesn't show up in an edge.

Comment: thank u very much jared ill continue with this.  best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have a Bipartite graph.  If you want each node to have degree 0, 1 or 2, one way to do this would be the following.  If you want to do a *matching*, either look up the algorithm (I don't remember it), or change maxDegree to 1 and I think it should work as a matching instead.  Regardless, let me know if this doesn't do what you want.

```
def hamiltPath(graph):
    """This partitions a bipartite graph into a set of components with each
    component consisting of a hamiltonian path."""
    # The maximum degree
    maxDegree = 2

    # Get all the nodes.  We will process each of these.
    remaining = graph.vertices()
    # Create a new empty graph to which we will add pairs of nodes.
    newGraph = Graph()
    # Loop while there's a remaining vertex.
    while len(remaining) > 0:
        # Get the next arbitrary vertex.
        node = remaining.pop()
        # Now get its neighbors that are in the remaining set.
        neighbors = [n for n in graph.neighbors(node) if n in remaining]
        # If this list of neighbors is non empty, then add (node, neighbors[0])
        # to the new graph.
        if len(neighbors) > 0:
            # If this is not an optimal algorithm, I suspect the selection
            # a vertex in this indexing step is the crux.  Improve this
            # selection and the algorthim might be optimized, if it isn't
            # already (optimized in result not time or space complexity).
            neighbor = neighbors[0]
            newGraph.addEdge(node, neighbor)
            # "node" has already been removed from the remaining vertices.
            # We need to remove "neighbor" if its degree is too high.
            if len(newGraph.neighbors(neighbor)) >= maxDegree:
                remaining.remove(neighbor)

    return newGraph


class Graph:
    """A graph that is represented by pairs of vertices.  This was created
    For conciseness, not efficiency"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = set()

    def addEdge(self, a, b):
        """Adds the vertex (a, b) to the graph"""
        self.graph = self.graph.union({(a, b)})

    def neighbors(self, node):
        """Returns all of the neighbors of a as a set. This is safe to
        modify."""
        return (set(a[0] for a in self.graph if a[1] == node).
                union(
                set(a[1] for a in self.graph if a[0] == node)
                ))

    def vertices(self):
        """Returns a set of all of the vertices. This is safe to modify."""
        return (set(a[1] for a in self.graph).
                union(
                set(a[0] for a in self.graph)
                ))

    def __repr__(self):
        result = "\n"
        for (a, b) in self.graph:
            result += str(a) + "," + str(b) + "\n"
        # Remove the leading and trailing white space.
        result = result[1:-1]
        return result


graph = Graph()
graph.addEdge("0", "4")
graph.addEdge("1", "8")
graph.addEdge("2", "8")
graph.addEdge("3", "5")
graph.addEdge("3", "6")
graph.addEdge("3", "7")
graph.addEdge("3", "8")
graph.addEdge("3", "9")
graph.addEdge("3", "10")
graph.addEdge("3", "11")


print(graph)
print()
print(hamiltPath(graph))
# Result of this is:
# 10,3
# 1,8
# 2,8
# 11,3
# 0,4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer jared, I have been looking at your code but I am unsureits doing what I hope.  Sorry I will continue to work on this.

Comment: Could you give some example input and output graphs, then?

Comment: def addEdge(self, a, b):
        """Adds the vertex (a, b) to the graph"""
        self.graph = self.graph.union({(a, b)})

syntax eror

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I use 3.2 and I'm new to Python (I'm familiar with programming and graph theory though).  Based on the documentation it appears that each argument to union needs to be iterable (http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html).  With my code, I think a and b are a tuple.  Probably something like:  self.graph.union([(a, b)]) so that it's a list of a tuple.

Comment: for some reason your code it kicks out nodes 5-9 every time (using the modified version i posted). starting with `G= my_bipartite_geom_graph(10, 10, 1, 2)` then 'a=hamiltPath(G)' and `a.nodes()`

Comment: i added `newGraph.add_nodes_from(G.nodes(data=True))` in the code and now it returns a graph where all nodes are within the max degree

Comment: Congrats!  Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is your problem but my wtf detector is going crazy when I read those two final blocks:

```
while nodesa:
     u,du = nodesa.pop()
     pu = du['pos']
     for v,dv in nodesb:
         pv = dv['pos']
         d = sum(((a-b)**2 for a,b in zip(pu,pv)))
         if d <= radius**2:
             G.add_edge(u,v)

for n in nodesa:
    mu = du['G.degree(n)']
    while mu > 1:
        G.remove_edge(u,v)
    if mu <=1:
       break
```

- you never go inside the for loop, since nodesa needs to be empty to reach it
- even if nodesa is not empty, if mu is an `int`, you have an infinite loop in in your last nested `while` since you never modify it.
- even if you manage to break from this `while` statement, then you have `mu > 1 == False`. So you immediatly break out of your `for` loop

Are you sure you are doing what you want here? can you add some comments to explain what is going on in this part?

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks for your comment. After posting this  have realised just how flawed this code is, much more than I thought.  Basically what my beginners brain was trying to do was go through all the nodesa after network formation. and for every nodea i wanted to delete a random edge from the node until all nodesa only have one edge each.

Comment: @user1317221 I think you need to work on your code. Your question is currently unanswerable. You should work on your own, and come back you you have a precise problem